# How to call SQL Server stored procedure with so many parameters in python?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pypyodbc

I have to insert records in a db table with more than 50 columns. I know how to call stored procedure with parameters in Python like this:

```
 self.__createConnection()
    proc= "{call faftech..Hns_HolidayCheck (?)}"
    ls=[]
    ls.append(dateTime)
    param= ls
    self.__cursor.execute(proc, param)
    val= self.__cursor.fetchone()
    self.__closeConnection()
```

I want to know the best way to insert the data in the table with so many columns. I am using pypyOdbc.

Comment: In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with simply passing the parameters the way you describe.

The only small improvement that I can suggest is to name your parameters. E.g. `proc = "EXEC faftech..Hns_HolidayCheck @some_date = ?"`. This will minimize the risk of mapping mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's sadly no easy way to do this.  The best way is to provide the `table_name`, `column_names`, and `values` and build up the sql by yourself:

```
def insert_row(self, table_name, column_names, values):
    params = [ '?' ] * len(values)
    params = ','.join(params)
    column_names = [ f'[{x}]' for x in column_names ]
    column_names = ','.join(column_names)
    sql = f'insert into [{table_name}] ({column_names}) values ({params})'
    conn = self.getConnection()
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        conn.execute(sql, values)
```

Alternatively, you can send in a dict of `column_name`s => `value`s:

```
def insert_row(self, table_name, values):
    params = [ '?' ] * len(values)
    params = ','.join(params)   
    q, column_names = [], []
    for column_name, value in values.items():
        q.append(value)
        column_names.append(f'[{column_name}]')
    column_names = ','.join(column_names)
    sql = f'insert into [{table_name}] ({column_names}) values ({params})'
    conn = self.getConnection()
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        conn.execute(sql, q)
```

Alternatively, you can use django which will make this much easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Since the columns are more than 10 it is good to create a table type in SQL and pass a table as a parameter to the stored procedure